# steps for Windows azure Database connectivity

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, azure, cloud

I'm developing Windows Phone application using Visual Studio 2010 using C# for database  connection plan to use Windows Azure. Will you please say the steps? I have to call my web services into my app. How I access my REST  web services in my Windows Phone ap? I need a C#  coding for that too.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best approach now for this is using Windows Azure Mobile Services, please have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/get-started-wp8/) which explains how to use it with Windows Phone 8